# Visual Studio Code Sencha Ext JS Extension Issue

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, model-view-controller, extjs, visual-studio-code

I'm learning Ext JS so I installed the `Sencha.vscode-extjs` extension v1.0.1 in my Visual Studio Code (which is new as well, just downloaded today).  I want this plugin because I saw where you can put your cursor on something like a controller and do `Control+MouseClick` and it will open that file.  Very handy when dealing with large Ext Js apps.  But I can't seem to get that feature to work.  I keep seeing `No definition found for 'main'`...

[image]

I have verified that the extension did finish indexing everything by looking at the `vscode-extjs.log` file.  It did take a very long time to index because I also have all the example Ext Js apps.  Any idea what I'm missing?  Thanks!

**UPDATE**: The controller is in the same folder, see image...[image]

Comment: Where's the code for the controller?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli I updated the OP to answer your question. Thanks!

Comment: Where is the code for the controller? I can see it's not been placed in your requires block there.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli it is in the requires block, `'Earthquakes.view.main.MainController'`. The app works just fine. This was straight from Sencha training, I didn't edit anything. So I'm pretty sure it's structured properly. The trainer can `Control+MouseClick` on things like that and it will open the file where that class is defined but he can't remember how he got his VSCode to be able to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I finally figured it out.  I can now `Ctrl+Hover` over extend, controller, requires, etc... and it will show a popup of its definition and when I `Ctrl+MouseClick` (or press `F12`) it opens that file.  What I did to make it work was I opened just a single Ext JS app folder then waited for the plugin to index everything.  That's it.  Before, I had my entire "Projects" directory open in Visual Studio Code which contained about 8 sub folders all of which were Ext JS apps.  So maybe there were naming conflicts between the different apps or maybe this plugin just wasn't intended to work with multiple apps at once.